# Unable to build GCC due to c++11 errors

Tags: c++, build, g++

I need an older version of GCC for installing CUDA toolkit, as CUDA toolkit does not support GCC newer than 5.3.1, and the Fedora machine I am trying to install it on comes with GCC 6. I don't have much control over the machine, so I have had to resort to building GCC myself. The steps I have followed are:

```
$ cd gcc-5.3.0
$ contrib/download_prerequisites
$ cd ../build
$ ../gcc-5.3.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/local/gcc-5.3.0 --program-suffix=5.3 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-checking=release --with-tune=generic
$ make
```

This results in successful `configure`, but `make` fails with error:

```
cfns.gperf:101:1: error: ‘const char* libc_name_p(const char*, unsigned int)’ redeclared inline with ‘gnu_inline’ attribute
```

There are a whole bunch of other C++11 warnings as well. After some google searches, I figured that this had to do with building GCC 5 or older with GCC 6. I thought it might help if I could force the compiler to follow C++98 instead. So, I tried:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++98"
$ ../gcc-5.3.0/configure ...
$ make
```

Didn't work. I still keep getting the same C++11 warnings, with build failing with the exact same error. Then, I tried:

```
$ ../gcc-5.3.0/configure CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++98" ...
$ make
```

Again, same error. I peeked at the Makefile this time, and it sure had `CXXFLAGS` set to `-std=gnu++98` here and there. Also, I have tried to build GCC 4.9.3 as well to see if this is a problem tied to a specific release, but I got the same error again.

I am not sure how to proceed further. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html, `gnu_inline` is a gcc extension to pre-c99 C code. Since you have the source code, you can locate the file that causes the error and try to change the offending declaration to `inline` so that it follows the C99/11 and C++ syntax, or to `__INLINE` or `__inline__`. My guess is, your C++ code includes some headers written for pre-C99 c code. More info here: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-08/msg00375.html

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I tried the changes as mentioned in the referenced link, it got me much further than the earlier error, but eventually it failed with error ``gcc-5.3.0/gcc/cp/except.c:1043: undefined reference to `libc_name_p(char const*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status``.

Comment: try those solutions one by one? https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+reference+to+%60libc_name_p&rlz=1CAASUE_enUS669US669&oq=undefined+reference+to+%60libc_name_p&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case someone else had this problem, apparently it's fixed by this [patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=ec1cc0263f156f70693a62cf17b254a0029f4852). If you make the suggested changes (which would be too verbose to mention here, but are simple enough to be done manually) to the GCC source files, then `configure` and `make` successfully work without the need to pass `-std` options. I successfully built GCC 5.3.0 using GCC 6.2.1 with these changes to the source files.

Comment: Got following error ```In file included from ../.././gcc/cp/except.c:1023:0:
../.././gcc/cp/cfns.h:31:9: error: "cfns" is not a valid filename
 #line 3 cfns.gperf"```. Is it possible to build older gcc(5.3.1) using higher verssion(7)

Comment: I tried using this for gcc-4.8.5 and now hitting this error: ./md-unwind-support.h:141:18: error: field ‘uc’ has incomplete type
  struct ucontext uc;

Comment: Its curious why they release a version of GCC that doesn't compile?

Comment: Fo the ucontext compile failure i found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566650/how-do-i-compile-gcc-5-from-source